# grep command for last nth line

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a grep command returns more than 20 lines. I need to display the 4th line from last line of the grep result,

lets say my file has below data,

test.txt

```
one  
two  
three  
four  
five  
six  
seven  
eight  
nine  
ten
```

Task is :

```
grep "nine" test.txt // i want seven as result
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: I don't understand. How can `grep "nine"` return the line with `seven` in it?

Comment: i want result "seven" although i am using search string as nine. last nth line of the result using grep/awk/sed.

Comment: `seven` is 2 lines before `nine`, your question says "4th line" before the match.

Comment: Your `grep` command produces only one line of output.  What is the 4th line from the end of one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the nth line from the end, then clearly your input is limited so you don't need a streaming solution.  So you might as well reverse the input and print the nth line from the beginning:

```
grep ... | tac | sed -n "${n}{p; q; }"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-B` option in `grep` to take any number of lines before your search line and then `head -1` will get you the first line from output:

```
grep -B2 nine file | head -1

seven
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file
one  
two  
three  
four  
five  
six  
seven  
eight  
nine  
ten
```

You can use `awk` to keep `n+1` number of lines in a buffer and then print the line that is `n` lines before the match:

```
$ awk -v n=2 'BEGIN{b=n+1} { buf[NR%b]=$0 } /nine/{ print buf[(NR-n)%b] }' file 
seven
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk -v s=nine '$0~s{print q}{q=p;p=$0}' file
seven
```

Explained:

```
awk -v s='nine' '   # search string into s var
$0~s { print q }    # if match, print buffer q
{ q=p; p=$0 }       # q is previous of previous
' file
```

If there's going to be only one match you can add `exit` after the `print q;`.